# Pool name error with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a function in Python 2.7 using the multiprocessing module. Unfortunately, in my pool function I seem to be getting an error when passing in multiple arguments. I have tried to pack them as a list of tuples, as a class, and as a list of lists and all seem to give me the following error:

```
  File "plot_gfs.py", line 132, in plot_data
results = pool.map(plot_var,args)
File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
raise self._value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This is my parallel function code:

```
def plot_data(lats, lons, bounds):

    lons2, lats2 = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

    x, y = basem(lons2, lats2)

    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    args = [('prmslmsl', 0, 'jet', 950, 1050, i, x, y, bounds)
            for i in range(80)]
    results = pool.map(plot_var, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

As a note: the plot_var function tag is:

```
def plot_var(var_in):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the arguments as a tuple:

```
results = pool.map(plot_var, (args))
```

or, depending on your usage:

```
results = [pool.map(plot_var, a) for a in agrs]
```

Comment: Passing the arguments as a tuple produces the same error. 

I'm working on getting your second solution working, but it appears to be passing each value of my tuple individually (so it is passing element 1 of tuple 1, element 2 of tuple 1, etc)

Comment: I figured out why your second solution didn't work- it doesn't match my usage. I have a list of tuples, and I'm trying to map plot_var to each tuple.

Comment: args is a list of tuples, correct?  If so, you should be able to iterate over it to obtain the tuples, e.g. args = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)], >>> [a for a in args]
Out[4]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]

Comment: Could you provide the header of that function to indicate its usage?

Comment: I'm sorry- the first example did end up working- my target function had a new error. Sorry. Answer accepted.